# Why does my switch turn on one outlet and off another?

Tags: electrical

I have a wall switch that turns on one outlet but turns off another outlet at the same time. Am I missing something or what is the purpose of this? Ideally I would have one outlet on all the time while the other is controlled by the switch for a living room lamp.

Any information or advice would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch and outlet boxes in question?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we could help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Did you just move into the house?

Comment: What specifically should the picture include? Just simply with the cover off?

Comment: Yes I did just move into the apartment

Comment: This is not  a common application for switching outlets. It was probably originally wired the way you'd  like it and it can be corrected to do that but some inside the box and inside the outlet box would be needed.  It  was probably  modified to accommodate  switching two devices that could not run at the same time, like two space heaters..... maybe for an elderly person.

Comment: Apartment?  Are you renting? **You cannot work on electrical in rental units.  No one can, except for a licensed electrician**.  Not even the landlord!  Obviously, you don't have the legal right to alter wiring in a building you don't own, and the landlord isn't allowed either to prevent slumlords from doing incompetent bodge jobs.

Comment: An apartment, yes. Renting, no.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a 3way switch that was wired to power one device in up and another in down , but more likely a DIY screwup that thought this was a way to power an outlet, I have seen this a few times.

Comment: Thank you all for your insights. I will post pictures as soon as possible when I am back at the apartment.